# Show days and events only of the current month in the fullcalendar.io

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

In the 'Month' view of the fullcalendar.io I would like to display the **current month only**, with the current month events. However, currently what is being showed is a month counting from the current date.

> E.g: If today's date was 2016-20-03...
>   - What fullcalendar display: *From: 2016-20-03 To: 2016-19-04* 
>   - What I would like to display: *From 2016-01-03 To: 2016-31-03*

After reading the documentation and looking up around I couldn't find any variable or set up for the fullcalendar to achieve this so I thing that I will have to modify the fullcalendar.js

Has someone already done this?

**View**

```
$('#' + engineerId).fullCalendar({
            header: false,
            views: {
                plainMonth: {
                    type: 'basic',
                    duration: { days: 31 },
                    buttonText: 'Month'
                },
                plainWeek: {
                    type: 'basic',
                    duration: { days: 7 },
                    buttonText: 'Week'
                }
            },
            firstDay: 1,
            dayNamesShort: ['S', 'M', 'T', 'W', 'T', 'F', 'S'],
            defaultView: 'plainWeek',
            theme: true,
            viewRender: function (view, element) {
                $('#CalendarViewObject').val(view.name);
                viewName = view.name;
            },
            aspectRatio: ratio,
            editable: true,
            eventLimit: false, // allow "more" link when too many events
            events: {
                startEditable: false,
                durationEditable: false,
                url: window.location.href.toString().split(window.location.host)[1] + '/GetEmployeeEvents',
                type: 'POST',
                data: function () { // a function that returns an object
                    $("[id^=qtip-]").empty();
                    $("[id^=qtip-]").remove();
                    return {
                        serviceAreaId: serviceAreaId,
                        employeeId: engineerId,
                        calendarViewObject: $('#CalendarViewObject').val()
                    };
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert('there was an error while fetching events!');
                }
            },...
```

**Controller**

```
public JsonResult GetEmployeeEvents(DateTime start, DateTime end, string queueName, string employeeId, string calendarViewObject)
```

The 'start' and 'end' dates are set up by the fullcalendar.io, and those dates are the ones that I would like to change.

Thank you very much in advance,
Alvykun

Comment: full calendar sends its current visible range.  Not sure if you can disable showing parts of the pre/next month as when there is space it finishes the month. However, you can do this wherever you fetch the event list from, or even in jQuery during the initialization of fullcalendar. Perhaps show some code for where you are getting your event data and language used to generate them.

Comment: Hi @warath-coder, thank you for you answer. I have uploaded my fullcalendar code.

Comment: So you have a server backed sending json objects back correct? Is it working ok except the date range? Show that code as well.

Comment: Yes, @warath-coder, I have a server sending json objects. Yes, it is working correctly :D. What code would you like to see? The event rendering code?

Comment: So use that to send only the current month events

Comment: I tried to but it didn't work. Somehow fullcalendar sends his own dates (the specified above..)

Comment: in your controller, change the start and end dates (use the ones provided by the calendar to help determine which month you are displaying) some basic math/checks can do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some more research in the fullcalendar documentation, I ended up by setting the following:

```
$(\'.calendarClass\').fullCalendar(\'gotoDate\',new Date(y, m, 1));
```

This did the trick and works!

Comment: I use your code on "eventAfterAllRender" and it works!!. Thanks